# What's the difference between various $TERM variables?

Tags: terminal

I tried vt100, vt102, vt220, and xterm by using `top`.

But I can't find their difference. Is there any other term type? What's their difference?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`xterm` is supposed to be a superset of `vt220`, in other words it's like `vt220` but has more features.  For example, `xterm` usually supports colors, but `vt220` doesn't.  You can test this by pressing <kbd>z</kbd> inside `top`.

In the same way, `vt220` has more features than `vt100`.  For example, `vt100` doesn't seem to support <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Compare their features and escape sequences that your system thinks they have by running `infocmp <term type 1> <term type 2>`, e.g. `infocmp vt100 vt220`.

The full list varies from system to system.  You should be able to get the list using `toe`, `toe /usr/share/terminfo`, or `find ${TERMINFO:-/usr/share/terminfo}`.  If none of those work, you could also look at [ncurses' terminfo.src](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html), which is where most distributions get the data from these days.

But unless your terminal looks like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Terminal-wyse50.jpg) or [this](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/3270-01.jpg), there's only a few others you might want to use:

- `xterm-color` - if you're on an older system and colors don't work
- `putty`, `konsole`, `Eterm`, `rxvt`, `gnome`, etc. - if you're running an XTerm emulator and some of the function keys, Backspace, Delete, Home, and End don't work properly
- `screen` - if running inside GNU screen (or tmux)
- `linux` - when logging in via a Linux console (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>)
- `dumb` - when everything is broken

Comment: Is that the full list of terminal type? Thank you~

Comment: @sam No, this isn't the full list. These are common ones. Anyone can invent a new terminal type, in principle. You can see what terminal types are available on your system by running `ls /lib/terminfo/* /usr/share/terminfo/*` (these are the paths on Debian, other distributions may have slightly different paths). Most of them are highly exotic.

Comment: for a explanation of the codes have a look at: http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GVTT_termdef

Comment: `vt220` supports colours!  I had one with orange on black!  ;-)  Sorry.

Comment: @Kusalananda The first one having colors was vt241... All the vt220 you can find are white, green or orange, depending on the phosphors used...

Answer (score 14):

Run infocmp wihtout any argument will give you all available xterm alternatives:

```
$> infocmp
xterm|xterm-debian|X11 terminal emulator,
    am, bce, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,
    colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,
    ...
```

For more info check

```
$> ls /lib/terminfo/x/
xterm         xterm-256color  xterm-color     xterm-debian    xterm-mono
xterm-r5      xterm-r6        xterm-vt220     xterm-xfree86
```

Comment: Did Mac OS have the terminfo directory?

Comment: this answer is not right. running `infocmp` without argument gives you the settings **for the active terminal**. to list the other terminals you use `toe`

Comment: @zx1986 there is `/usr/share/terminfo` directory on a macOS.

Comment: @Zombo: that `toe` utility reference is really useful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the old days, "terminals" were separate devices. Some were paper and ink ribbon, some were "glass keypunches". There were many manufacturers. In addition to the text, the manufacturers wanted non-text (invisible) ways of invoking terminal-specific behavior, thus, "control characters" and "escape sequences". Since there was no standard, different manufacturers could choose different escape sequences for the same function (on their own terminals). Rather than setting each escape sequence (on this terminal, Here's how to clear screen, here's how to position the cursor, etc), setting the `TERM` environment variable acts as a key into a terminal info database, holding all the settings for that terminal. See `man terminfo terminfos tput stty`.

Digital Equipment Corporation (DEC) manufactured a popular glass keypunch, the VT100, followed by the VT220, whose control sequences were adopted by the Unix community.

"Control characters" (which differ from "characters" by having their. 7th bit (0x40) cleared, see `man ascii`) were inherited from the still earlier TeleType (a complex electro-mechanical marvel manufactured by The Phone Company (back when there was just one)) that was used for text transmission.

You, running a "terminal emulator", in a graphics canvas, in a window, on a screen, can only confuse the terminal emulator by futzing with `TERM`. `TERM` is used to make "mostly compatible", serially connected, different hardware machines "work" with Unix.

The history of serial communication is fascinating, as its reflection in Unix/Linux device interfacing If it works, keep it. If a "better" way comes along,  use it. There's always someone, somewhere using a 110 baud Model 33 TeleType.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $TERM`:

Inside tmux: gives `screen-256color`

Outside: gives `xterm-256color`

Some keys, such as <kbd>Home</kbd>  and  <kbd>End</kbd> behave differently.

Type `cat` then press some keys to see the difference between different `$TERM`.

---

`infocmp xterm-256color screen-256color | less`

Many `NULL` under screen-256color

```
    comparing xterm-256color to screen-256color.
        comparing booleans.
        bce: T:F.
        ccc: T:F.
        mc5i: T:F.
        npc: T:F.
        comparing numbers.
        comparing strings.
        acsc: '``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~', '++\,\,--..00``aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~'.
        clear: '\E[H\E[2J', '\E[H\E[J'.
        cnorm: '\E[?12l\E[?25h', '\E[34h\E[?25h'.
        cuu1: '\E[A', '\EM'.
        cvvis: '\E[?12;25h', '\E[34l'.
        ech: '\E[%p1%dX', NULL.
        enacs: NULL, '\E(B\E)0'.
        flash: '\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l', '\Eg'.
        initc: '\E]4;%p1%d;rgb:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\', NULL.
        invis: '\E[8m', NULL.
        is2: '\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>', '\E)0'.
        kDC: '\E[3;2~', NULL.
        kEND: '\E[1;2F', NULL.
        kHOM: '\E[1;2H', NULL.
        kIC: '\E[2;2~', NULL.
        kLFT: '\E[1;2D', NULL.
        kNXT: '\E[6;2~', NULL.
        kPRV: '\E[5;2~', NULL.
        kRIT: '\E[1;2C', NULL.
        ka1: '\EOw', NULL.
        ka3: '\EOy', NULL.
        kb2: '\EOu', NULL.
        kbeg: '\EOE', NULL.
        kc1: '\EOq', NULL.
        kc3: '\EOs', NULL.
        kend: '\EOF', '\E[4~'.
        kent: '\EOM', NULL.
        kf13: '\E[1;2P', NULL.
        kf14: '\E[1;2Q', NULL.
        kf15: '\E[1;2R', NULL.
        kf16: '\E[1;2S', NULL.
        kf17: '\E[15;2~', NULL.
        kf18: '\E[17;2~', NULL.
        kf19: '\E[18;2~', NULL.
        kf20: '\E[19;2~', NULL.
        kf21: '\E[20;2~', NULL.
        kf22: '\E[21;2~', NULL.
        kf23: '\E[23;2~', NULL.
        kf24: '\E[24;2~', NULL.
        kf25: '\E[1;5P', NULL.
        kf26: '\E[1;5Q', NULL.
```