# How shall I find out all the terminal types that can work?

Tags: terminal, docker

How shall I find out all the terminal types that can work?

**On Lubunu 18.04,** The followings work

```
$ TERM=xterm top
$ TERM=vt100 top
```

but the following don't:

```
$ TERM=lxterminal top
'lxterminal': unknown terminal type.
$ TERM= top
TERM environment variable not set.
```

The following returns nothing, which is said to give all the terminal types that can work

```
$ toe
```

**In a docker container**, the following works

```
$ sudo docker exec -t 851 top

$ sudo docker exec -t 851 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=851fbf59c6da
TERM=xterm
HOME=/root
```

but why do the following don't

```
$ sudo docker exec 851 top
TERM environment variable not set.

$ sudo docker exec 851 bash -c "TERM=xterm top"
top: failed tty get

$ sudo docker exec 851 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=851fbf59c6da
HOME=/root
```

Why doesn't prefixing a command with `TERM=xterm` work in a container while it does in Lubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing the `-t` flag when you called `sudo docker exec 851 bash -c "TERM=xterm top"`

Comment: I am not. That is for "Why doesn't prefixing a command with TERM=xterm work in a container while it does in Lubuntu?"

Comment: _Because_ you missed the `-t` after `exec`.   So no terminal was associated with the `exec`.  So  `top` said "no terminal"

Answer (score 1):

The [*ncurses-bin*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/amd64/ncurses-bin/filelist) package includes [**`toe`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/toe.1m.html), which lists terminal descriptions.

As for which ***work***, that's accomplished by reading the documentation for the terminal, which should tell you what it does.

Comment: `toe` returns nothing.  How does it explain why some works, some don't?

Comment: you gotta read the manual page, which answers this "toe returns nothing".  That's not the documentation for your ***terminal***.

Comment: Thanks. (1) How can I find out what is my terminal and what is the documenation for my terminal? (2) by reading the manpage, do you mean I should run `toe -a`?  (3) `man toe` says "With no options, toe lists all available terminal types by primary name with descriptions", what does it mean by "all available terminal types by primary name with descriptions"?

Comment: Actually none of the answers are very good, but [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43945/whats-the-difference-between-various-term-variables) gives some hints.  There are other questions asking related things, but I don't see any that are useful.